# In Safari, XML response is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

WE have tried like this, Please check and give suggestion.

```
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{ 
    var objXMLHttp=null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        objXMLHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        objXMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }
    return objXMLHttp;
} 


function show(url,did)
{
    divId=did;
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
        return;
    }
    if(url.indexOf("?")!=-1)
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
    else
    url=url+"?sid="+Math.random();

    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.send(null);

} 

function stateChanged()
{ 

    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
    { 
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your code doesn't use jQuery, and you don't mention how its relavant to the question I removed the tag.  Please feel free to add some more information if you actually had a jQuery related question

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you're using jQuery at all here. Ajax is handled very differently across browsers, but jQuery provides abstractions so you don't have to worry about it.
Look in to the API docs, either the lower-level `.ajax()` method, or some of the even simpler shorthand methods such as `.get()` and `.post()`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: can you give me another solutions,

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing logical `||` operator with `&&`:

```
function stateChanged()
{ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
    { 
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}
```